# Hora incorrecta en zona horaria America/Lima

Tags: date, hardware

Buenas soy de Peru y hasta hace poco me esta saliendo la hora incorrecta en mi proyecto de Laravel, el `timezone` lo tengo configurado a `America/Lima` como dice la documentacion. Investigue la causa del asunto y no encuentre respuestas, solo esta pagina que tambien sale la hora incorrecta igual que el mio

- https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/es/city/3947322

El proyecto lo tengo localmente y sale la hora incorrecta, pero en el servidor si sale normalmente.

Estoy usando Laravel 5.3 y PHP 5.6.4

**Edit-01:** Intente obtener la fecha actual por php puro con lo siguiente, pero de igual forma sale incorrecta la hora, ¿Tal vez sea problema de mi PHP? No modifique nada de ahi. Aunque de igual manera, ¿Porque en esa pagina tambien le sale la hora incorrecta?

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Dónde configuraste la zona horaria?

Comment: @BetaM en el `config/app.php` me salia correcto la hora, pero como dije hasta hace poco ya no, la pagina que puse es un ejemplo de lo que me sale a mi (hora incorrecta)

Comment: @BetaM aun sigo sin encontrar respuesta, por donde empezaria a buscar?

Comment: Hola. Trata de verificar antes el valor actual. `$dateobj = date_create();
        $currtimezone = date_timezone_get($dateobj);
        $currnametimezone = timezone_name_get($currtimezone); echo $currnametimezone;` y nos muestras qué devuelve

Comment: @quevedo me sale "America/Lima"

Comment: Entonces, **supongo que Laravel la establece por cuenta propia** en algún momento después y no encuentra en alguna preferencia de usuario una opción de cambio y pone su propio default. `Verifica los usos de date_default_timezone_set()` y, trata de insertar un var_dump instantes antes de devolver la página para tratar de ver que usa.

Comment: ¿Cuál es sistema operativo tienes en local?

Comment: @Sal estoy utilizando windows

Answer (score 1):

Buenas estimado espero que se encuentren bien para resolver este problema tienes diferentes formas de hacerlo hay una forma usando [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) que es un paquete de composer que tiene muchas cosas resueltas con referente a fechar, pero la forma de hacer la nativa en el lenguaje es de la siguiente forma:
[Listado de Reference time zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)

```
<?php
$timestamp = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Lima'));
$nows = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $nows;
```

Espero que le sea útil.

Comment: Esta configuración mediante Laravel ya la tiene el OP de acuerdo con sus comentarios hechos

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que el OP indica que usa XAMPP:

para manejar todo tu entorno local con una sola zona horaria te recomendaria ir a tu `php.ini` y editar la variable de fecha:

```
date.timezone = America/Lima
```

deberías de encontrarla similar a esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante que hagas la verificación en el archivo uy busques si existe alguna otra declaración de `date.timezone` y todos los coloques en la misma zona horaria.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay unos puntos que quiero comentar en lo que vi:

1. El problema era de mi pc, mas especifico de mi reloj interno (se habia malogrado), yo veia la hora correcta, asi que no sabia eso
2. Sobre la pagina que puse, veia "incorrecta" la hora por el problema anterior mencionado
3. En conclucion fue un problema de hardware, aunque la respuesta de @Francisco es muy util y espero que les sirva a los demas

Comment: @BetaM cierto, eso mismo le pregunte a CandidMoe https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol?_=1907155419